# How come iframing this page is not working in Safari, but it does work in Firefox, etc.?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I took on a job and I simply can't figure out how to get it to work.

I'm trying to put this URL in an iframe that takes up the whole page: https://www.alliedautoins.com/vautogeneric7_button2/step1.html

The problem is, on the first page of my form, when I enter my zip and click "Get Quote", the spinning wheel just spins forever and doesn't open the next page in the frame.

When I open the page in firefox, it works perfectly.

i've been using different variations of this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
 <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<meta name="robots" content="noindex">

    
 <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }
        </style>

</head> 
<body>
<div id="content">
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.alliedautoins.com/vautogeneric7_button2/step1.html"></iframe>

</div>

 </body></html>
```

I've tried about 20 different variations, but nothing seems to work.  I'm trying to get it working here: https://www.insurancepanda.com/datalot/form.php

Comment: _"an iframe that takes up the whole page"_... sounds super dodgy

Comment: [Safari has dev-tools](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/safari/sfri20948/mac) just like Firefox and Chrome. Do you see any errors reported in the console?

Comment: Phil - no errors that I see. The issue is I cannot edit the page inside the frame. Do not have access to it. I assume the error is there.

Comment: Seems that they don't send the appropriate cookies and the session there doesn't recognize us... Doesn't seem easy to workaround.

Comment: If you go in Safari's settings and untick "Prevent cross-site tracking" then it will work fine. I doubt there is anything you can do on your end however. You'd have to see with the owners of the website you embed for they make it more embeddable friendly.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido. That works for me too. I will try and get the website owners to make it more embeddable friendly.